# Creating new user account and sending email

Tags: java, spring-mvc

My method for user account creation is as below,

```
      public String saveAccountInfo(User user) {

    if(null != user){
        userService.addUser(user);
        mailService.sendActivationEmail(user);
    }

    return "redirect:/greeting.html";
}
```

When user submits the account creation form, greeting.html is not displayed until "sendActivationEmail" successfully sends email. sendActivationEmail takes longer and thus it is taking long for user to see greeting page. How can i just trigger this method and allow flow to complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task of sending activation mail can be done by another thread. This will allow you to display greetings page.

```
if(null != user)
{
    userService.addUser(user);

    Thread mailSenderThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            mailService.sendActivationEmail(user);
        }
    });
    mailSenderThread.start();
}
```

Something like this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You have to start a new thread and send the email from within the new thread.

That's pretty much the only way you can achieve asynchronous processing in Java.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have done it,

```
     public String saveAccountInfo(final User user) {

    if(null != user){
        user.setActivationKey(generateRandomKey());
        userService.addUser(user);
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mailService.sendActivationEmail(user);                  
            }               
        }).start();
    }       
    return "redirect:/greeting.html";
}
```